# I'm using symfony2 with HwiAuth bundle for registration

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm using symfony2 with HwiAuth bundle for registration. and i dont know how to publish post to facebook page because i have already the token for users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can.

This response was about posting a tweet on twitter with this bundle:
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/473

> Sorry but no, this is not point of this bundle, this bundle allows to authenticate out of box, but you can study used code and do it on your own. But I would recommend to use library that was created for such purpose like Twitter API calls.

You'll probably want to use the facebook sdk: 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Or even easier, just use one of those "Share on Facebook" buttons, and customize the button.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button